# How to add Azure subscription key header to JAX-WS SOAP message

Tags: azure, soap, header, jax-ws

I am trying to send a SOAP message through Azure and I need to add the subscription key to my JAX-WS message.

```
    NewSubscription_Service test = new NewSubscription_Service();
    NewSubscription newSubscription = test.getNewSubscription();
    WSBindingProvider binding = (WSBindingProvider) newSubscription;

    binding.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, soapEndpointUrlAzure);
    binding.setOutboundHeaders(
            Headers.create(new QName("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"),"xxx")
    );
```

When I try to send this message it will give me a 401 with this explanation:
Access denied due to missing subscription key. Make sure to include subscription key when making requests to an API.

Should I add the header in another way? I'm not that used to SOAP messages, so any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that you should not use outboundHeaders for this.
The code below is how you should add the headers:

```
    Map<String, List<String>> requestHeaders = new HashMap<>();
    requestHeaders.put("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", Arrays.asList("xxx"));
    binding.getRequestContext().put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, requestHeaders);
```